# Python Spark Databricks binary classification tutorial - How to make prediction for unlabelled data?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I hope it's ok to ask a question related to a specific tutorial. Maybe someone on here used the same tutorial and knows the answer.

I'm following [Databricks tutorial for binary classification](http://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/binary-classification-mllib-pipelines.html), using the [Kaggle Titanic Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic).

The tutorial works with a labelled dataset. The following steps are performed:

- Preprocessing: Indexing all categorical features, putting all features in a vector called "features".
- Building a model
- Evaluating the model
- Make predictions

The tutorial uses a big, labelled dataset which is split into a train and a test to build the model and later evaluate it. I got this working with my train dataset without problems.

Now I want to make predictions for a separate 'test' dataset from Kaggle which doesn't have labels (in my case the "survived" column, in case of the tutorial the "income" column is missing).

Does anybody know how to approach this? 
Do I have to perform the whole preprocessing part of the tutorial separately on the test dataset and then call the below:?

```
finalPredictions = bestModel.transform(preprocessedUnlabelledTestDataset)
```

Or do I maybe need to add the missing label column (income/survived) to the test dataset, then do the preprocessing and then call the above?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to use the tutorial model for the titanic data set. Easiest way to go about it is this:

Add the cols name, and add a column called train_or_test.

Then do the SQL conversion and then the pre-processing.

Then substitute this line

`(trainingData, testData) = dataset.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed = 100)`

for

`trainData = dataset.filter([dataset.train_or_test ==1)  # assuming train is set to 1
testData = dataset.filter(dataset.train_or_test ==0)  # assuming test is set to 0`

then drop the cols and proceed as you were.